# how can i add my current projects in new folder in svn commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i have solution which consist multiple project now i want that when i commit the prject it will goes under some specific folde.

example

like this is my original solution

[image]
here u can see thay my **timeclockwindowservice** project comes under windows service project
but when i commit this project in svn and tack full update in different pc its seems like this

[image]
here u can see that my **timeclockwinowsservice** does not comes under in windows service project
means the point it windows service folder not created automatically or not it appear while commiting project

how can i commit project with its outer folder

Comment: Are using a plugin like AnkhSVN or how do you use SVN?

Comment: i am using TortoIesSVN

Comment: so did you add the project to SVN and did you add the solution file? I would recommend to use a plug-in like AnkhSVN which takes care of putting the right files under version control